# What is the maximum number of SHA-1 hashes?

Tags: hash, cryptography, sha1, sha, hash-collision

Clearly since SHA-1 hashing produces 40 characters each time, there is a finite number of possible hashes—does anyone know exactly how many?

Comment: It doesn't "produce" 40 characters. It does produce 160 bits of hash. If you see them in hex format, you see 40 hex digits.

Comment: No. 40 signed/unsigned chars are "normally" 320 bits (8 bits/char). A SHA-1 is 160 bits = 20 bytes = 40 hex digits. You asked a precise question about how many SHA-1 hashes are there. Just to make an example, if I write a SHA-1 in base64 I get a string long 28 characters (of which 1 is fixed and is the terminating `=`)

Comment: Okay, SHA-1 hashes consist of 160 bits = 40 hexadecimal digits, commonly encoded into a 40 character string if that makes it better. My last comment was indeed incorrect, which is bad considering I have written a tight SHA1er in C.

Comment: My fear was that you were a junior programmer that thought the DVD-ROM was a cup holder :-) But if you wrote a SHA-1er then you can think whatever you want of SHA1 hashes :-) In this case it becomes an "informed choice" :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SHA-1 hashes have 160 bits, so 2<sup>160</sup> of them.
(2<sup>160</sup> = 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 ~= 1.46 x 10<sup>48</sup>)

Note that since you have a much larger message space than possible hashes, collisions are bound to occur.

Also note that the probability of collision is much higher than you might think. At just 2<sup>80</sup> messages the probability of a collision is 50%, thanks to the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack). (ie: with just 23 people the probability that 2 people have the same birthday is 50%).

Comment: I guess the question asks whether the hash function is surjective, though.

Comment: Google calc: 1.46150164 × 10^48 :-)

Comment: I'll add that the number of possible SHA-1 is very near the sqrt([googol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol)) (a factor of only 100) :-) :-)

Comment: @NullUser: You seem to be mixing surjective and bijective. Having a proof of either surjectivity or non-surjectivity would both quite likely constitute a break of some kind of the function. Have a look at [Is SHA-512 bijective when hashing a single 512-bit block?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-sha-512-bijective-when-hashing-a-single-512-bit-block/304#304) for a similar question (and answer).

Comment: I'll buy you a beer if you can generate a SHA1 collision. Or even if you can generate 2^80 messages without one.

Comment: @Nick I'll do it if you buy me a large enough server :)

Comment: @NullUserException How large is large enough? ;)

Comment: 2^80 = 1,208,925,819,614,629,174,706,176. A distributed systems that is able to handle 1 billion SHA1 hashes per second would likely take no less than 1,208,925,819,614,629 seconds to find a single collision. 1 trillion SHA1s per sec would be 1,208,925,819,614 seconds. Good luck!

Comment: Hash collision probability calculator, might be useful for others too: http://everydayinternetstuff.com/2015/04/hash-collision-probability-calculator/

Answer (score 11):

SHA-1 produces 160-bit outputs, and it *should* be able to produce just about any sequence of 160 bits, There are 2<sup>160</sup> such sequences, i.e. close to 1461 billions of billions of billions of billions of billions. That's kind of big.

*However* we have no proof that every single one of them is reachable. It would be bad for SHA-1 security if the number of possible outputs would be significantly lower than 2<sup>160</sup>; for instance, if only 1/4 of them were reachable (2<sup>158</sup>), security against preimage attacks would be divided by 4, and security against collisions would be halved. No such issue is currently known with SHA-1 (there *are* known weaknesses of SHA-1 when it comes to resistance to collisions, but not *that* one).

It is possible (but it would be at least mildly surprising) that a few 160-bits outputs cannot be reached. It is expected that this will be remain *unknowable*. To some extent, being able to **prove** that SHA-1 possible outputs cover the whole 160-bit space would be worrisome: such a proof would require a good deal of analysis of the mathematical structure of SHA-1, and the security of SHA-1 largely relies on such an analysis being intractable.

Answer (score 1):

SHA-1 is made up of 5 32 bit integers.

That's 4294967296^5 or 2^160

or  1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976 possibilities

*To put that into perspective*

Total Possible SHA-1 Values: 1,461,501,637,330,902,918,203,684,832,716,283,019,655,932,542,976

Total gallons of Water on Earth: 365,904,000,000,000,000,000

That includes every ocean, sea, lake, swimming pool, bath tub, etc - [source](http://ga.water.usgs.gov/edu/earthhowmuch.html)

The possibility of collisions is only theoretical at this point. Still waiting to hear of one.

Comment: If I may ask, what is a Collision?

Comment: Two random records of the same value.